# eatmydata on OS X

Tags: macos, linker

Does [eatmydata](http://www.flamingspork.com/projects/libeatmydata/) work on OS X? If so, how do you enable it? On ELF-based systems, you would set the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable, but I believe that OSX has a different kind of linker, and this wouldn't work.

Comment: FYI: OS X uses Mach-O binaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` variable to point to the `libeatmydata.dylib` file, and set `DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1`. For example:

```
$ DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Users/lorin/libeatmydata/.libs/libeatmydata.dylib DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1 ./fsynctest
```

To build on OS X from the libeatmydata bzr repository, do:

```
$ bzr branch lp:libeatmydata
$ cd libeatmydata
$ autoreconf -i
$ ./configure
$ make
```

The `libeatmydata.dylib` file will be in the `.libs/` directory

Comment: I needed eatmydata on OS X right now and downloaded libeatmydata-59.tar.gz.  It needed some manual tweaking to get it to compile as Mac OS X doesn't define off64_t, replacing all off64_t with off_t got the compile to work, although with a few warnings.